# Native status bars

Tags: java, swt, statusbar

Is there a way to create *native* status bars in SWT like those found in Windows applications:

[image: Windows status bar]

I have seen status bars simulated using labels, but I am more interested in a true solution.

Answer (score 1):

org.eclipse.jface.action.StatusLineManager.createControl(), or getControl(), returns a status line control. This control is, of course (being SWT), native.

Comment: Can you confirm that `StatusLineManager` is, in fact, native? I only ask this because not all SWT controls are native (though many tend to be). SWT was considered the "half-way" between AWT (which restricted itself to only include the controls native to *all* supported platforms) and Swing (did not include any native controls).

Comment: I only meant that the StatusLine object is built out of native objects and resources.  It's not a wrapper around a windows status bar class (e.g., msctls_status32), if that's what you mean.  I don't think swt has one of those.

Answer (score 0):

There is a status bar available in [JIDE Components](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/component.htm) but I'm afraid you will have to pay for it.

I'm not affiliated with JIDE but I do licence their products and would recommend them.  I'm afraid I've not tried using them with SWT but there is some information [here](http://www.jidesoft.com/forum/viewtopic.php?=&p=12327) that suggests that they should work.

You can always get a trial licence and try it out.

[image: Screenshot of JIDE controls]

Comment: @IngoKegel sorry, I'm not used to the SWT/Swing divided, I've checked and it may still be pertinent as JIDE suggest that there is a way to use their components in SWT in the link I have added.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like long standing change request: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=88837