# Does Python have a cross-platform GUI toolkit that uses native widgets?

Tags: python, user-interface, cross-platform, native

Python has [many GUI toolkits](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming). If I understand correctly, these toolkits typically take on the responsibility of rendering their own widgets (rather than relying on the operating system). This achieves cross-platform support at the cost of having widgets that don't necessarily look, feel and behave exactly like their native counterparts. Does Python have a GUI toolkit that is cross-platform *and* takes advantage of each system's native widgets?

According to [GUI Programming in Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming), there are at least two candidates:

## [Lucid](http://www.lucidtoolkit.org/)

Unfortunately, this library seems to have disappeared. It's link now redirects to [Icy Labs](https://secure.icy.com.au/home/), a company that "designs and distributes components and devices for electronics and robotics development" (???).

## [PySWT](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/zilin/pyswt/pmwiki.php?n=PySWT.Introduction)

This is a port of the [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) library for Java (which I am already familiar with). This library doesn't *feel* like Python (for example, it retains the `set*` and `get*` methods that are common in Java). Therefore, I am curious to know if there is a more authoritative library that meets my needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is wxWidgets an option? As far as I know, it integrates with whatever the OS has to offer - win32 on windows, gtk on Linux and, I think, Aqua on OSX.

Comment: This library looks very promising! [One of the first example programs](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started#Adding_a_menu_bar) even overcomes [a known shortcoming I have with SWT](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2117057/41619)!

Comment: @Adam wx is pretty good, but there are still compatibility issues around. As long as there are tests for this, there shouldn't be problems though.

Comment: @Dana the Sane: Where can I learn about these compatibility issues?

Comment: @Adam I'm not aware of a catalogue of issues, I'm only speaking about those that I encountered.

Answer (score 4):

What about Qt?

And it's attendant wrapper, PyQt?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyQt

Qt for the most part looks native. I don't think you'll ever find a cross-platform toolkit that is uses native widgets exclusively and still be cross-platform. Those goals are to some extent mutually exclusive.

Comment: Qt has a [widget gallery](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/gallery.html) so the asker can decide for himself if Qt looks native enough, which I think it does.  Also, I'll note that the KDE4 style isn't on there.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I already knew about Qt, but I was looking for something even closer to the native look-and-feel (Qt applications have typically felt "different" to me). I agree that the goals seem somewhat mutually exclusive, so I should clarify what I meant. I was thinking from the mindset of SWT which attempts to render everything natively, unless the platform does not have such a widget. In that case, SWT resorts back to rendering the widget itself on that platform.

Comment: I just noticed on Wikipedia that (recent versions of Qt use the native APIs of the different platforms to draw the Qt controls, and so do not suffer from such issues)[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(framework)#Use_of_native_UI-rendering_APIs]. Therefore, I was mistaken about it. I will have to give it another look.

Answer (score 3):

[pyside](http://www.pyside.org/) LGPL bindings for qt. Note there is also PyQt which is GPL or paid for closed source use.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! However, I would prefer something truly native (although Qt makes a valiant attempt at emulating it). :)

Comment: according to wikipedia: Qt used to emulate the native look of its intended platforms, which occasionally led to slight discrepancies where that emulation was imperfect. Recent versions of Qt use the native APIs of the different platforms to draw the Qt controls, and so do not suffer from such issues.

Comment: Thanks for that comment! I also noticed that comment. I will have to give Qt another look.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Toga](http://toga.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) recently. Think it's new, still missing a lot of native widgets but is pretty easy to pick up.