# Python front-end GUI for Linux

Tags: python, linux

I'm planning to take a non-GUI Linux distro (no Gnome, KDE, etc) and build my own front-end GUI for it. While I have a few years of Python programming experience, I have never attempted to do something quite like this.

To be more specific about my project, I'm building a CarPC and I have everything pretty much worked out so far, except the front-end. Most pre-existing front-ends for CarPCs run on Windows and the ones that run on Linux are hard to find (they either quit development or only run on specific hardware). My front-end will always be full-screen and I do not want to run a desktop environment unless I absolutely have to; it would just slow down the boot time and provide unnecessary features.

My question is basically where I should start. **What Python graphics libraries are out there that would allow me to build a front-end GUI without a desktop environment?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably want to look at other answers and questions on this topic such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718878/does-python-have-a-cross-platform-gui-toolkit-that-uses-native-widgets)

Another good link is [this one](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) on the Python websitewhich lists different GUI toolkits.

While I haven't used it, Kivy looks like a good place to start. It's apparently got touch screen capabilities which I assume you would use and it doesn't look constrained to a GUI desktop env.

Hopefully you can find a way to do this without a desktop env. If not perhaps consider using X11 as your layer and go from there.

Comment: Wow, Kivy looks perfect for my uses. I will definitely be checking into it more. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably consider [DirectFB](http://directfb.org/). You can even use a DE on it if you like (although not required).

Answer (score 1):

[WxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) is awesome. I use it with Python and plain WxWidgets in C++ too. I've had great luck with making native GUIs from it and internationalization is supported too. Good luck!

Edit: I missed the "without a desktop environment bit". I'm not sure my answer is relevant. You should edit the Title of the question. Just disregard.