# Is there any of python's GUI framework that support Windows 7-style file choosers?

Tags: python, user-interface, windows-7

I want to use win 7 style file chooser in python.
This is the same question like: 
[Does Swing support Windows 7-style file choosers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703825/does-swing-support-windows-7-style-file-choosers) just in PYTHON.
I tried Tkinter, easygui but both of them looks like this:

[image: Annoying old style file chooser]

But I prefer this dialog:
[image: Preferred dialog]

python-course.eu mentions that Tkinter's look and feel depends on the system, but I try this and its dialog has the old style on win 7.
More detail: http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_dialogs.php

Thanks Benedek

Comment: related: [Does Python have a cross-platform GUI toolkit that uses native widgets?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3718878/4279)

Answer (score 1):

PyQt and/or PySide can do that. Here's a shot of a Qt file dialog in Windows 7. Note the custom icon, window title, and file format filter (*.txt):

[image].